# Build a Perspective from Fragment with Eclipse e4

Tags: eclipse-rcp, e4

Is it possible to define a perspective stack and perspective in the fragment.e4xmi?
The *Eclipse 4 model editor* doesn't seem to allow it. Why?

I add a new Model Fragment and for *Feature Name* I click *Find ...*.
When I want to add a Perspective or a Perspective Stack, the dialog greys out the OK-Button.

[image: Find Feature Name - OK Button greyed out]

Also, I have a lack of understanding what this Dialog is showing in general. It lists certain UI Elements and a lot of items below them, like

- children
- handlers
- menus

and so on.
But those are listed multiple times. For example *children* is listed under CompositePart and under Dialog. But it doesn't make any difference which one I chose.

[image: It doesn't make a difference which children item is chosen.]

I know I can define the Perspective in the `plugin.xml` using the extension point and implementing `IPerspectiveFactory`. Is there no way to do it with the fragment.e4xmi?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about that dialog as I don't usually use it.

What you want to add is a Model Fragment with the 'Extended Element-ID' set to the id of the TrimmedWindow you want to put the perspective in. The 'Feature Name' would be `children`.

The model editor should then let you add a "Perspective Stack" as a child.

You can add the Perspective to the stack.

Note: Using the plugin.xml and IPerspectiveFactory is for Eclipse 3.x compatability mode, not pure e4. If you are using compatability mode I'm not sure how defining a perspective in the model editor fits.

Comment: Is compatibility mode something I can turn off or is it just the same for using Eclipse 3.x along with e4?

Comment: Compatability mode is when your code is using any org.eclipse.ui.xxx plug-ins rather than just the core e4 plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Even if the question is older, here is a current answer (since I was looking for that myself)

I understood this to mean that you want to add a perspective to an existing application through model fragment. as shown in the picture
[Model Fragment Definition Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUyqX.png)

Extended Element ID: Here you link the perspective stack from your main application -> so you can change the perspective later
[Extended Element-ID Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tvpX.png)

Feature Name: Here take children List<Perspective> from PerspectiveStack -> allows you to create perspectives as a child
[Feature Name Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARJ2r.png)

and you're done...now set your dependencies and you can change the perspective via code :)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35492402)